# 128 bit Int in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: c#, sql-server, int, 128-bit, bit-manipulation

I'm looking for the best way to implement 128 bit unsigned integers in SQL Server. The main requirement is that it *must* support bitwise operations across all 128 bits. (Is this even theoretically possible on a 64 bit machine? I digress.)

I've read about some implementations using C# and user-defined types via a CLR assembly, but I couldn't determine if that would support bitwise operations.

Has anyone successfully done what I need to do? Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: I realize this question is almost 5 years old; however as to "theoretically possible on a 64-bit machine" the answer is - of course. On most processors, you can do shift and/or arithmetic operations "with carry". For example, on an 8-bit processor with this feature (even on the 6502 your Commodore 64 used), any overflow would go into a "carry" bit which could be factored in the operation on the next byte. Doing 128-bit arithmetic was therefore possible on an 8-bit architecture, albeit almost exclusively from assembly language (most high-level languages are ignorant of carry bits)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Database side, I'd use a `binary[16]` column.

Then in clr code code you can overload the bitwise operators within a custom type:

```
public struct My128BitValue
{
    private readonly long _l1;
    private readonly long _l2;

    public My128BitValue(long l1, long l2)
    {
        _l1 = l1;
        _l2 = l2;
    }

    public static My128BitValue operator &(My128BitValue left, My128BitValue right)
    {
        return new My128BitValue(left._l1 & right._l1, left._l2 & right._l2);
    }

    public static My128BitValue operator |(My128BitValue left, My128BitValue right)
    {
        return new My128BitValue(left._l1 | right._l1, left._l2 | right._l2);
    }

    public static My128BitValue operator ^(My128BitValue left, My128BitValue right)
    {
        return new My128BitValue(left._l1 ^ right._l1, left._l2 ^ right._l2);
    }
}
```

CLR basic example here, you need to complete `FromByteArray` and `ToByteArray` methods:

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{    
    [SqlFunction()]
    public static SqlBinary bitwiseAnd128Bit(SqlBinary lhs, SqlBinary rhs)
    {
        My128BitValue v1 = My128BitValue.FromByteArray((byte[])lhs); //explicit conversion
        My128BitValue v2 = My128BitValue.FromByteArray((byte[])rhs);
        My128BitValue result = v1 & v2;
        return result.ToByteArray(); //implicit conversion
    }
}
```

From SQL you can then run `bitwiseAnd128Bit` on two columns.

Read more about CLR here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Not really "no trouble". One of the operands must be an `int` so it's not straight forward to do bitwise operations beyond the fourth byte (or beyond the 8th byte if `bigint` also works)

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I will give it a try. Can you give an example of how a My128BitValue variable would me declared and used in SQL (after the CLR has been implemented)?

Comment: @ambient Added example.

Comment: Weston - just got back around to this. This solution works great and was very easy to implement. I actually find it to be an extremely elegant and creative solution as well. Thanks!